# Как вынуть данные из файла в таком же порядке, в котором их записал?

Tags: java, файлы, хранение-данных

Я записал в файл следующее:

```
try {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Saved.ser");
    fileWriter.write(w + " " + d + " " + l);
    fileWriter.close();
     } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Где `w`, `d` и `l` - созданные переменные типа `int`. Как мне вынуть данные в таком же порядке из этого файла и присвоить их переменным `w1`, `d1` и `l1`?

Вынимал следующим образом, однако он просто строкой вынимает:

```
try {
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Saved.ser"));
  StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
  String currentLine;
  while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      stringBuffer.append(currentLine);
  }
  bufferedReader.close();
  System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
} 
catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Просто не хотелось бы создавать отдельный файл под каждую переменную, потом вынимать её, парсить из `String` в `int` и присваивать переменным.

Comment: а в чем заключается проблема в цикле while сплитить полученную строку по пробелу, парсить данные и присваивать переменным?

Comment: в том, что не очень понимаю как это сделать.. есть пример?

Comment: final int w = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[0]); final int d = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[1]); final int l = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[2]);

Comment: спасибо, не знал, что в файле также элементы есть [], все заработало

Answer (score 0):

```
String values = currentLine.split(' ');
int w = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
int d = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
int l = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
```